# Docker: EACCES: permission denied - RUN vs CMD

Tags: linux, docker

I'm trying to run react app via Docker and face the **EACCES: permission denied** issue.

I found the following solution:

```
// this worked for me

RUN chown -R node:node /app/node_modules

// or sh into docker container and run

chown -R node:node /app/node_modules
```

I add **RUN chown -R node:node /app/node_modules** into my Dockerfile, but that did not fix the issue.

Only when execute the second one in the container console/shell it works.
My question is WHY?

My Docekrfile:

```
FROM node:18-alpine

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./

RUN npm install
RUN chown -R node:node /app/node_modules
RUN set NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096

COPY ./ ./
    
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

and my docekr-compose

```
version: '3'
services:
  express-server:
    container_name: react-dc
    restart: always
    build: .
    command: npm run start
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
      - /app/node_modules
```

Comment: (The `RUN chown` probably isn't necessary at all.  Without it, your library files will most likely be owned by root, and world-readable but not writeable; that's an appropriate and usable set of permissions for your application code, you shouldn't ever need to write to the `node_modules` directory while the application is running.)

Comment: Sure, but when react is initializing, there is something trying to create .cache folder in some of the node_modules folder

Answer (score 2):

Everything you do in the container's `/app` folder is overwritten by the volumes declaration in `docker-compose.yml`.

This:

```
volumes:
- ./:/app
```

means "throw away anything you might have in `/app` and use what I have on host in the current folder. Even more, everything in `/app` inside the container is now owned by `root`.

To fix this remove the volumes declaration (both entries) in `docker-compose.yml`

Comment: If I remove the volumes the auto refresh will be disabled, when I edit the code. Since I read your comment I realize that I did not ignore the node_modules folder for the volume scope. I add .dockerignore file with node_module folder and all run smooth. Thanks

Comment: I understand now what you want it for. From personal experience using Docker for development is fun at the beginning but slowed me down on the long run. So I'm not doing it anymore (it's ok for small changes, especially for tools that are not worth installing just to change a few lines of code). If you keep the volumes, then you can remove `COPY . .` and make your build faster.